# Python Dictionaries Named with Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, variables

I have a dictionary of dictionaries which each contain lists which are to be appended to as required in another part of the program.

The names are created using for loops such that a dictionary exists for each combination...

```
first_entry = {'column_a': [0], 'column_b': [0]}

dictionary_of_dictionaries = {}

for a in list_1:
    
    for b in list_2:

        dictionary_name = str(a + b)
        
        dictionary_of_dictionaries.update({dictionary_name: first_entry})
```

The idea was to be able to access these dictionaries later on by rebuilding the names as above and plugging that into the dictionary_of_dictionaries and from there the individual dictionaries can be appended to as necessary...

```
for a in list_1:
    
    for b in list_2:

        dictionary_name = str(a + b)

        dictionary = dictionary_of_dictionaries[dictionary_name]

        # example 
        dictionary['column_a'].append(x)
        dictionary['column_b'].append(y)
```

Later on all the dictionaries are exported to csv in the same way (for loops to rebuild the names, then exporting them)...

```
for a in list_1:
    
    for b in list_2:

        dictionary_name = str(a + b)

        dictionary = dictionary_of_dictionaries[dictionary_name]

        dictionary_columns = dictionary.keys()

        dictionary_df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, columns=dictionary_columns)

        dictionary_df.to_csv(os.getcwd() + '/' + dictionary_name + '.csv')
```

Unfortunately though when this happens, even though all the dictionaries should be somewhat unique, all the csv files are identical.

Which part(s) of my process is flawed and can I achieve this functionality?

Many thanks for any insights.

Comment: How do you create `first_entry`? If you create it outside the loop, it's possible that your `first_entry` is a list _shared_ among all the dictionaries. Try replacing `dictionary_of_dictionaries.update({dictionary_name: first_entry})` with `dictionary_of_dictionaries.update({dictionary_name: first_entry[:]})` or, more simply, `dictionary_of_dictionaries[dictionary_name] = first_entry[:]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, moving the first entry into the loop has done it. The first entry is just a placeholder since the contents of each dictionary is used later on in the program and it needs something to start it off if that makes sense? I had assumed that it wouldn't make a difference where the first entry was!